# Pushing a single file to a different repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am currently working on a project and I want to push commits to a single file from a repository to another repo in Azure DevOps. The files and folder structure of these repositories are wildly different. I want to automate this process using Azure DevOps pipelines.

So the workflow would look something like this:

- push changes to repository
- In pipeline take single config file
- push file to another repository

```
.
└── example
    └── for
        └── stackoverflow
            └── fileToPush.json
```

```
.
└── json
    └── fileToUpdate.json
```

I have a hard time figuring out how to do this. Is this even possible?
Any suggestions to point me into the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the available REST APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't do "changes" or "files". It does *commits*. The Azure DevOps web interface probably gives you an interface for making a new file, pasting content into it, and adding a commit for that file; or you could do the same thing locally if you have a clone of the DevOps repo, i.e. just make a new file in the working tree for that repo, paste the content, save, and add-and-commit (and push) as usual.

Comment: Doing this manually unfortunately isn't an option. But thanks for your reply I adjusted my post accordingly. So if I understand it correctly; there is no way to push a single file from one repo to another without pulling the repository and changing it's contents? For example using Azure DevOps pipelines.

Comment: I don't know whether the pipelines can help with this, so let's let this sit for a while and see whether someone has a suggestion along those lines.